# How to copy and paste text in Selenium Python when we have gotten code.text

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]I'm trying to perform a copy and paste to another website and I've looked this question up but I didn't understand the solutions.

I'm trying to copy this block of text which I have been able to target, as you can see printing code.text gives me the respective lines I want to copy. I'm using a Macbook so OS X.

Comment: Copy text from where? paste it where? can you show some snippet?

Comment: Copy that block of text, the solution

Comment: Follow this answer --> [entering-python-code-in-textarea-using-sendkey-but-not-working-any-solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63752733/10911205)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you get then text from a webpage and you wanna send it in an other input area for example ?

If it is that, you can try to put this text in a variable, something like that :

```
text = code.text
```

and then you find the area with driver.find_element_by_xpath('') for example and you type :

```
area.send_keys(text)
```

It will work like that...
I don't know if you understand what I suggest ? :)

Comment: This doesn't work because I need to switch to a new window and when that happens `code.text` doesn't exist anymore since it's not on the current window

Comment: Mhhhh i don't  understand why it doesn't work if you put your code.text in a local variable in your program, it exists until the end of the program. An other solution could be to write the code.text in a .txt file and when you wanna access it you ll have to read it. But I don't think it's the right solution. Maybe I didn't understand your problem