# .send_keys in selenium is messing up indentation when using with pyperclip

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyperclip

I'm copying some code from Leetcode to paste in Github, I use pyperclip to paste and copy into clipboard using Selenium. Everything is saved as a string but when i use driver.send_keys(pyperclip.paste()) this is what happens
[image]

I've verified that the issue is not Leetcode or Github by copying from Leetcode on my own and then pasting it to Github. The issue is pyperclip because when I paste this is the format

[image]

However the issue clearly gets amplified when I use driver.send_keys() because as you can see from the first image that the indentation increases way too much

Here's my code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import pyperclip


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://github.com/login?return_to=%2Fjoin')

github_username = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="login_field"]')
github_username.send_keys('')

github_password = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="password"]')
github_password.send_keys('')

github_login = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="login"]/form/div[4]/input[9]')
github_login.click()

sleep(3)
url = "https://github.com/user/Leetcode"
driver.get(url)

sleep(3)

leetcode = 'https://leetcode.com/accounts/login/'

driver.execute_script('''window.open("{}","_blank");''')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get(leetcode)

sleep(3)


# driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

leetcode_username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_login"]')
leetcode_username.send_keys('')

leetcode_password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_password"]')
leetcode_password.send_keys('')

leetcode_login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="signin_btn"]')
leetcode_login.click()

# click on problems
sleep(3)
problems = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="lc_navbar"]/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[3]/a')
problems.click()

sleep(3)
order = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="question-app"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/table/thead/tr/th[1]')
order.click()
order.click()

sleep(3)
rows = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="question-app"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody[2]/tr/td/span[1]/select')
rows.click()

all = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="question-app"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody[2]/tr/td/span[1]/select/option[4]')
all.click()

for i in range(6, 68):
    current_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="question-app"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr[6]/td[3]/div/a')
    current_link.click()
    sleep(3)
    submission = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/a')
    submission.click()
    sleep(3)
    accepted = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a')
    accepted.click()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
    sleep(3)
    code = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ace"]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]')

    pyperclip.copy(code.text)

    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
    driver.get(driver.current_url)
    sleep(3)
    add_file = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="js-repo-pjax-container"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/details/summary')
    add_file.click()
    create_new_file = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="js-repo-pjax-container"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/details/ul/li[3]/form/button')
    create_new_file.click()
    driver.get(driver.current_url)
    body = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="js-repo-pjax-container"]/div[2]/div/div/form[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]')
    print(pyperclip.paste())
    body.send_keys(pyperclip.paste())
```

Answer (score 0):

To paste the copied code you can use below JavaScript code and execute with the help of JavaScriptExecutor.

```
document.querySelector(".CodeMirror").CodeMirror.doc.children[0].lines[0].text = code
```

Note : Here code the string containing the code. in code editor the code will be shown in single line but when you preview this or save you can see the proper formatted code.